# How to do a Common Session storage for both Http and websocket server?

Tags: php, apache, session, websocket, slim

I have been trying to built Chat application in my website. I have using slim php as my API for normal HTTP request for forms and results. since, i need to implement user chat. so I have implemented web-socket using ratchet library that works perfectly. But the problem is I don't how to globalize the session storage for both http server and websocket server as I am using slim framework. Any help or guide please.

Thanks